# string.Format Return value of pure method is not used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, string.format

I am using razor to display decimals from my view model and then trying to format the decimals into currency:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Order != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Order.Where(x => x.OrderInStep2 != null))
    {
      String.Format("{0:C}", item.OrderInStep2)
    }
}
```

I am getting an `Return value of pure method is not used` warning, but I thought it should still work. However, the formatted item is not displaying at all. It does display when I take away the formatting though. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render the value in a code block like this:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Order != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Order.Where(x => x.OrderInStep2 != null))
    {
      <text>@String.Format("{0:C}", item.OrderInStep2)</text>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just run the code, and do nothing with the result.

Put the result within text tag:

```
<text>String.Format("{0:C}", item.OrderInStep2)</text>
```