# Decimal return in currency format

Tags: c#, decimal, currency

is it possible to return decimal from web service with value 0C instead of 0M. return type must be decimal so converting to currency string option doesnt work.

decimal return value is `0M` but in response it is shown as  `<Money>0.0000</Money>`
value must be in currency format i.e. `0.00`

Maybe some DataAnotation would help?

Comment: What type of webservice, what is the interface, ...

Comment: A `decimal` has no formatting

Comment: Possible duplication [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741190/currency-formatting-mvc),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175921/string-formatting-with-currency-double-values-not-displaying-correctly),[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957318/string-format-return-value-of-pure-method-is-not-used)

Comment: `0.0000` and `0.00` are equal as a `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know two solutions to solve this problem.

**One**

Return strings:

```
string money = yourValue.ToString("0.00");
```

**Two**

Use [`Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round):

```
decimal money = Math.Round(yourValue, 2);
```

**Parsed**

It will always add `.00` to integer values.

```
decimal money = decimal.Parse(yourvalue.ToString("0.00"));
```

Comment: Funny how your Minion avatar looks left to my avatar, now that I've edited your question. I feel bad now…

Comment: Hahah :) You want that cookie? :D

Comment: first one does't wor for me couse return type must be decimal, the second one does the job converting from 0.0000 to 0.00, but what if i have initial value 2? it will still display 2 instead of currency 2.00. any ideas on that?

Comment: Why not to combine two of these approaches? I edited question.